# Can you delete LOG files in DB2

Tags: logging, db2

I have problem with my DB2 database, I cannot connect because I have full log file. Error that I get is:

```
SQL1762N  Unable to connect to database because there is not enough space to 
allocate active log files.  SQLSTATE=08004
```

If I do **df -h** command I see that logs directory is full.

```
/dev/dasdc1           2,3G  2,1G  125M  95% /
udev                  487M  184K  487M   1% /dev
/dev/dasda1            34M   16M   17M  50% /boot
/dev/dasde1           4,0G  2,0G  1,9G  51% /opt
/dev/dasdd1           349M  168M  163M  51% /var
/dev/dasdg1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  35% /db2/db2_1
/dev/dasdh1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_2
/dev/dasdi1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_3
/dev/dasdj1           6,8G  6,5G  9,7M 100% /db2/logs
/dev/dasdk1           6,8G  4,5G  2,0G  70% /db2/folder
/dev/dasdl1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_4
/dev/dasdm1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_5
/dev/dasdn1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_6
/dev/dasdo1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_7
/dev/dasdp1           6,8G  2,2G  4,3G  34% /db2/db2_8
```

My Question is, can I delete some old .LOG files in directory: **/db2/logs/db2inst1/MyDataBase/NODE0000/** ?

In this directory I see this directories:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 db2inst db2admin 4096 2018-11-22 20:20 C0000058
drwxr-x--- 2 db2inst db2admin 4096 2018-12-07 14:02 C0000059
drwxr-x--- 2 db2inst db2admin 4096 2018-12-14 10:53 C0000060
drwxr-x--- 2 db2inst db2admin 4096 2018-12-17 15:57 C0000061
drwxr-x--- 2 db2inst db2admin 4096 2019-07-14 22:07 C0000062
drwxr-x--- 2 db2inst db2admin 4096 2019-10-13 22:16 C0000063
```

Can I move/delete e.g. C000058 directory and reduce some free space. Because of this log files, I can't even connect do database to prune history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all archived logs if:

- You do not plan to use them again. It means, if you need to do a restore of the database and go to a point in time (roll forward), then you should not delete them.
- If you already copy them in a secondary storage, like a backup tool (TSM, Networker, Data Protector, Netbackup, etc.) you can delete them. Anyway, if you need to do a restore, you can recover the files from the backup tool.
- Each directory starting with a C, means Chain Log that is a set of logs that belongs to a different "branch" of the database. It could be due to a previous restores of the same database, or other thing related with logs. To be sure of the current head, check the database configuration for the head of the log. Any previous file could be deleted. For example, logs from November 2018, I think, they can be deleted.

Remember, these logs are only necessary in case of a point in time restore.

Answer (score 1):

According to the directory structure you provided, these are archived transaction logs.
You may delete / move them, if you:

- will not use them for rolling forward the database restored from a
  backup
- don't have some replication software, which may request some
  of these logs